# Async redis 'get' RuntimeError 'got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop'

Tags: python, flask, redis, python-asyncio

I have been trying to get async redis to work with async Flask app, but for the life of my, I can't figure out how to solve one problem. Here is the minimal reproducible code.

```
import asyncio
import redis.asyncio as redis
from flask import Flask

async def run_app():
    app = Flask('Flask')
    pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=6379, db=0)
    r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
    
    @app.route('/get', methods=['GET'])
    async def get_value():
        value = await r.get('key')
        return value
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run_app())
```

The requests are failing alternatively with the runtime error 'got Future  attached to a different loop'. I think it is because flask spins up the app with two threads, and each thread creates its own event loop. That's why one request behaves as expected and the second request throws the error and repeats indefinitely. When I run the app with `threaded=False` and `processes=2`, it works every time.

Would anybody like to chime in on how can I force all flask threads to use the same event loop? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried utilising the WSGIToASGIAdapter from asgiref? https://github.com/django/asgiref#wsgi-to-asgi-adapter
This should ensure that you only have a singular event loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and your temporary fix worked, so thank you!

However, reading through the Flask docs for async stuff (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/async-await/), they say:

> Async functions will run in an event loop until they complete, at which stage the event loop will stop. This means any additional spawned tasks that haven’t completed when the async function completes will be cancelled.

They then recommend switching to Quart if you primarily do async work in your app.  When I did that (for us it was a simple drop in replacement), everything worked perfectly.